# Redirect to correct packages in java compiled code JAR

Tags: java, primefaces, types, compiled

I get this error `"The type of <METHOD_NAME> is erroneous"` because the systems security area developed a JAR that loads the `menubar` and elements from the credentials it gets from the user profile keeped in the security system of sso. The thing is that it was developed for primefaces 3.1 where the component MenuModel was in the next package:   `org.primefaces.model.MenuModel`

We are now using primefaces 5.1 and that component is no longer in `org.primefaces.model.MenuModel` but in `org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel`

Obviously the JAR is compiled code, I just want to redirect to the correct package thats the only thing that prevents (hopefully) the app from running. How can I do that? :)

Comment: just three letters: why?

Comment: why are we using now primefaces 5.1? or why do I want to correct the package?

Comment: The latter of course. And it is not 'correct' the package, it is 'mess-up' the package. Correct it where it should be corrected. If that is to difficult than the full architecture is not good.

Comment: Well I guess you were right so I decompiled all the jar and re-make it. Since it wasn´t mine...I now did it my way. Thanks anyway.